# LaTeX/Sweave - How to reproduce code blocks in an appendix?

Tags: sweave

I hope this is in the right place. For my statistics assignments, I do the computation inline with Sweave, like so:

```
\begin{itemize}
 \item[Problem 1]
  <<label=block1,eval=T,echo=F>>
   varA <- 2+2
  @

  The answer to the problem is \Sexpr{varA}
\end{itemize}
```

I'd like to be able to reproduce the code in full in an appendix, but this doesn't work:

```
\subsection*{Code}
 <<block1>>
 @
```

There must be a clean way to do this that I'm missing.

Comment: Are you missing an `=` after the last`>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. as R. Schumacher mentioned, `<<>>=` and `@` must start on the first column;
2. `<<>>` is supposed to be used within a code chunk, so you have to put it under `<<>>=`;

Here is a complete example:

```
\begin{itemize}
 \item[Problem 1]
<<block1,eval=T,echo=F>>=
 varA <- 2+2
@

  The answer to the problem is \Sexpr{varA}
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Code}

<<all-blocks>>=
<<block1>>
@
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know I had to include <<block1>> in another block. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `<<>>=`  and `@` must start on the first column and nothing follows on the same line.

The file must be saved as **yourfilename.Rnw**, then run `Sweave(yourfilename.Rnw)` which will give you **yourfilename.tex** which now can be compiled with LaTeX.  Recommend that you put **yourfilename.Rnw** in a folder where only this project is done.