# Compiling a .tex file into many pdf without include?

Tags: compiling, sweave, split

I would like to have a single .tex file, with a main section and an appendix. I would want however to compile it into two distinct pdfs.

There are solutions using `\include`, see [How to create individual chapter PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/how-to-create-individual-chapter-pdfs) or [Splitting a large document into several files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29577/splitting-a-large-document-into-several-files), but this is not using a single `.tex` file. The reason I want a single `.tex` file is that I am using R Sweave, not showing input code in the main document, but want the input code to be shown in a companion document.

Following [LaTeX/Sweave - How to reproduce code blocks in an appendix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53787/latex-sweave-how-to-reproduce-code-blocks-in-an-appendix), my `.tex` file will be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Some stuff here to go in first pdf

<<block1,eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=
plot(density(1:10))
@

\appendix
Some stuff here to go in second pdf

<<all-blocks>>=
<<block1>>
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: In principle this is similar to common requests IF condition 1 make 1.pdf or IF condition 2 make 2.pdf OR OR see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162042/multiple-pdf-generation-with-one-tex-file?rq=1

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand.  Your linked [How to create individual chapter PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31334/107497) has several answers that use a single tex file (similarly for KJO's link).  Are they not sufficient?  But furthermore, why do you require only a single tex file?  Why not one tex file for the first part, and one tex file for the appendix, and include the code into both?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
\newif\ifmain
%\maintrue   %to be commented or not
\documentclass{article}
\ifmain
\let\olddocument\document
\let\oldappendix\appendix
\long\def\document#1\appendix{\olddocument\oldappendix}
\else
\def\appendix{\end{document}}
\fi
\begin{document}

Some stuff here to go in first pdf


\appendix
Some stuff here to go in second pdf

\end{document}
```